# Why does Laura never mention that she has been "sacrificed for a god"?

Tags: tv, american-gods

<sup>Note: this is the question about the TV Series</sup>

At the end of the first season, Laura asks Easter to resurrect her. Easter replies that she cannot help because Laura has been killed by a god - sacrificed for Odin

> [Easter] I can't help you with your dead.
>   You are dead of a different kind. [...] Laura Moon, you were killed by a god. I can't interfere with that. [...]
>
> [Laura] I was killed by a god? Which fucking god?
>   [Sweeney] Me fucking god. I ran you off the road. Ahh! That's right, I killed you! I killed you fucking dead! [...]
>   [Laura] She said that I was killed by a god. 
>   You are a lot of things, but you are not a god. Which fucking god?
>   [Sweeney] ... Wednesday

Yet in the next episodes, she doesn't mention it at all - either to her real killer or to Shadow, who continues to happily (more or less) working for Wednesday. If not for her husband's sake she could at least try to squeeze Odin by saying something like "Hey, if you won't help me, I'll tell Shadow that you've killed me and we'll see how this will affect your cooperation".

Why isn't she trying to tell that to anyone?

Comment: She doesn't want to mess with a God?

Comment: @AnkurRathee she actually hints it to Wednesday that she knows that he ordered Sweeney to kill her.

Answer (score 2):

Because it wouldn't matter. She's quite strong as far as undead go, but she's no match for Wednesday, even if he's quite "weak" compared to his "good" days. Nor would it help her, Shadow would most likely don't believe her directly, at that point he doesn't doubt Wednesday at all, after all, he witnessed his true name.

So who could help her? Maybe Anansi ? I doubt he'd care about her death, he might criticize Wednesday, but that's maybe all he'd do about it.

Blackmailing Wednesday works if she's in power, and he's not that hostile to her, he could help her if she asks nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Because Laura Moon forgets to tell since that part of her brain rotted. Others say she's scared of Odin but Odin is scared of her, reason he tries to keep Shadow from finding her.

Comment: Can you cite anything to support this?  That Odin is actually afraid of Laura?